# Add a group of options in a Magit transient

Tags: magit

I would like to add a group of options to a transient, but I cannot figure out the `POS` parameter I should use.

```lisp
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push "-n" ;; after the last option of the first group
  ["My group"
   '("-M" "My option" "--my-option")
    ])
```

does not work, it throws this error: "Cannot place ["My group"] into magit-push at -n; suffixes and groups cannot be siblings".

```lisp
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push '(0) ;; after the first group
  ["My group"
   '("-M" "My option" "--my-option")
    ])
```

does not throw any error, but when I try to open the push transient, I have this error: "No key for quote".

What is the correct way to add my custom group after the first group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue, the infixes in the group should not be quoted:

```lisp
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push '(0) ;; after the first group
  ["My group"
   ("-M" "My option" "--my-option")
    ])
```